# How to create an "alias target" A DNS record in Route53 for an elasticache replication group

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I'm creating an ElastiCache replication group for Redis with Cloudformation, which does not allow to specify the group name or clusters name (they are randomly generated gibberish).

So my idea is to create a DNS record to alias it, but I don't know how to get the hosted zone id for the alias target.

I could go for a CNAME, but if the A record alias option is possible I would rather do that.

Comment: Check whether ["Return Value" section on this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html#d0e38557) helps.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I don't think it helps, that's related to create a hosted zone in the template, I need to know the hosted zone id for a dns record that I don't manage (it is generated automatically by AWS when creating the elasticache)

Comment: I agree.  The ElasticCache Resource doesn't seem to return the values necessary to do a Alias (like the ElasticLoadBalancer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html#aws-properties-ec2-elb-ref : CanonicalHostedZoneName and CanonicalHostedZoneNameID )  However, it may be worth openning a question in the aws forum.

Comment: This is to bad that this doesn't work.

Comment: If you set the `ReplicationGroupId`, on the `AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup`, it will use that as the clusters name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not currently possible to create an Alias Target to an ElastiCache Replication Group.

According to the documentation section "[Choosing Between Alias and Non-Alias Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)" (emphasis/formatting mine):

> Instead of an IP address or a domain name, an **alias** resource record set contains a pointer to
>
> - a **CloudFront distribution**,
> - an **Elastic Beanstalk environment**,
> - an **ELB classic** or **application load balancer**,
> - an **Amazon S3 bucket** that is configured as a static website, or
> - another **Amazon Route 53 resource record set** in the same hosted zone.

ElastiCache is not in this list, so using a CNAME pointing to the replication group's endpoint (e.g., `!GetAtt ReplicationGroup.PrimaryEndPoint.Address` in your CloudFormation template) is your only option.

Comment: the 'p' in Endpoint needs to be upper case, i.e.,
`!GetAtt ReplicationGroup.PrimaryEndPoint.Address`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html#w2ab2c21c10d528c11

Comment: wouldn't that be a bit risky? Is the "PrimaryEndpoint Address" guaranteed not to change in the future? I would be cautious to go down that road.